# reshape pandas dataframe column with delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe (tab file with 2 columns-str) :

```
id1  id2

g1   ID:05434
g1   ID:05434
g1   NaN
g1   ID:05434|ID:38720|ID:33345
```

After doing

```
df1 = df[df['id2'].notnull()]
df2 = df1.drop_duplicates(['id1','id2'])
```

I got df2,

```
id1  id2

g1   ID:05434
g1   ID:05434|ID:38720|ID:33345
```

I am aiming to expand this to make it only 2 columns, say

```
id1  id2

g1   ID:05434
g1   ID:05434
g1   ID:38720
g1   ID:33345
```

Is there any expand function for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use[`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), also for remove `NaN`s is used [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

EDIT: By OP comment was removed duplicated in the end with sorting values:

```
df2 = (df.dropna(subset=['id2'])
         .set_index('id1')['id2']
         .str.split('|', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='id2')
         .sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2'])
         .drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']))

print (df2)
  id1       id2
0  g1  ID:05434
2  g1  ID:38720
3  g1  ID:33345
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael, your code was fine, but the duplicates still appeared due to sequence of methods. I modified it as the following: "df1 = (df.dropna(subset=['col2']).set_index('col1')['col2'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='col2').sort_values(by=['col1', 'col2']).drop_duplicates(['col1','col2']))". Adding sort_values and drop_duplicates gave me the unique sequences.